# Reducing image loading times?

Tags: javascript, css, image, compression, loading

I was wondering if there is any other ways to compress my images or any script that would load the page faster / or the the images behind the scenes?

The site is very interactive and using very high quality layers of images for the main layout. I have already saved for web devices in Photoshop and re-compressed using ImageOptim, some are jpeg but the majority are png24 to maintain transparancy, they are all set in CSS.

I have used jpegs and css sprites where i can but there is one in particular of a tree illustration streching the full site length, that is really slowing up the loading time, is there any I could compress these images further or code them differently that I missed?
Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You said you are spriting. That is good.

You can also use tools such as PNGcrush which attempt to make files smaller by dropping things such as meta data.

You should also send far distant expiry headers and use a cache breaker on your images, to ensure the images won't be downloaded again if unnecessary.

Comment: Hi, is pngCrush like ImageOptim I tried to download a version but cant seem to find one that works!   In terms of distant expiry headers and cache breakers this sounds a bit advanced for me would you know where to start or even a site with some good advice on implementing this. My site uses php, mysql, ajax and jQuery at the moment. any suggestions would be great thanks!

Comment: @Louise Basically, you tell the browser *don't download me again for a year*. This stops the browser needlessly requesting your images again. If you change them, you append a random string (can be the modified time) which shows as a new URL, forcing the browser to download this *new* asset.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop, choose file-> save for web, you will be able to find the best compromise between size and quality.

Comment: You can also take a look at advices about PNG's compression algorithm and make visually indistinct changes to your image to make it more compressible in PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the transparency there? PNG transparency is unsupported on some browsers and makes the page processing intensive and slow even on high end computers, depending on image size and quantity of layers. If you can show something of your site maybe someone can give more hints about how to optimize it.

Answer (score -1):

You can compress them on the fly with Apache if that's your web server. One of many available articles on the subject: http://www.samaxes.com/2009/01/more-on-compressing-and-caching-your-site-with-htaccess/

Comment: Compressing a png or a jpg using a webserver when they are already very efficient compression mechanisms does not make sense.